# Electron import library on remote with webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, import, electron

I am trying to convert my current code into a webpack js file. But I don't know how I can include a library on the remote variabel of Electron.

current code:

```
const { remote } = require('electron');
var windowManager = remote.require('electron-window-manager');
```

webpack file:

```
import {remote} from 'electron';
```

How do I import the windowManager on the remote import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how:

1.**In the main process**

```
const windowManager = require('electron-window-manager');
global.winMgr = windowManager;
```

2.**In The renderer process**

```
const {getGlobal} = require('electron').remote;
const winMgr = getGlobal('winMgr');
```